# How do I close my camera frame after reading/deciding a qr code with pyzbar?

Tags: python, django, opencv, qr-code

I've been working on this QR code scanner and so far I've gotten everything to work out;

- The camera works and the frame shows up.
- pyzbar decodes the QR codes I show it.
- regex slices the string I need within the decoded data.
- Text of the data is shown within the frame.
- Models are updated accordingly.
- and lastly I update my list for the time the QR was detected

The **Problem** is I actually want the frame to close when a **single** QR code is detected, decoded and all of the above process is completed.

**What actually happens** is after the frame is open it constantly and after it detects a QR code, it actually logs multiple (around 15) instances of a QR being detected after like 2 seconds. Also the frame is still up and I can still detect Images.

**The frame closes**, only after pressing the waitkey which is 27 or 'Esc'

I've tried adding this:

```
for obj in decodedObjects:
            id = re.findall('/attendees/confirmation/([0-9]+)', str(obj.data))
            cv2.putText(frame, str(id[0]), (50, 50), font, 3, (255, 255, 255), 2)

            attendee = get_object_or_404(Attendee, pk=str(id[0]))
            attendee.present = True
            attendee.timestamp = timezone.now()
            attendee.time_log.append(attendee.timestamp)
            attendee.save()

            if id is not None:
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
```

but obviously that won't work because it's inside the for loop...

> Here's the code:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Attendee

import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar

def qrscanner(request):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    context = {
        'scan': 'QR Successfully Scanned'
    }

    while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()

        decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(frame)

        for obj in decodedObjects:
            id = re.findall('/attendees/confirmation/([0-9]+)', str(obj.data))
            cv2.putText(frame, str(id[0]), (50, 50), font, 3, (255, 255, 255), 2)

            attendee = get_object_or_404(Attendee, pk=str(id[0]))
            attendee.present = True
            attendee.timestamp = timezone.now()
            attendee.time_log.append(attendee.timestamp)
            attendee.save()

        cv2.imshow("QR Reader", frame)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break


    return render(request, 'attendees/qrscanner.html', context)
```

So I am actually looking for **2 Things**:

- How to close the frame after detecting a QR Code?
- (additional question) how do I detect only **one** qr code (whether the frame closes or not). So when I scan the QR code, either the frame closes and I am left with one decoded data **OR** I scan the QR code and the frame remains open, until I hit 'Esc' and I am left with one decoded data.

Comment: Why not just use same if block at same place but return inside it -> if id is not None: return render(request, 'attendees/qrscanner.html', context) instead of break.

Comment: Tried it, and as expected the same result happened as with what I've tried. The one with if id is not None

Comment: So far I have not found the solution for this yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after some tests I found out these small edits would work out:

> first we add:

```
while id is None:
        _, frame = cap.read()

        decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(frame)
...
...
```

> then below we turn the while end function to:

```
if id is not None:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

That's it!